# Delphi XE2: firemonkey and IDirect3DTexture9

Tags: delphi, directx, delphi-xe, firemonkey

This is my biggest problem :( How can I draw IDirect3DTexture9 type object data to on some firemonkey control ?

Can I fill it like this ?

```
var
   tmpTexture: IDirect3DTexture9; // for example it's not empty
   panel: TPanel;
begin
  panel.Canvas.BeginScene;
  panel.Canvas.Draw( tmpTexture, nil, nil, nil, $FFFFFFFF );
  panel.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```